# String with linebreaks to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, express

I have an email that I want to parse and make a JSON of. The reason for this is to add the incomming emails to and database with the information.

I'm getting the plain email text and want to have this as JSON.
This is content as example:

```
"\ufeff \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nPostcode: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n1234aa \r\n\r\n\r\nPlaats: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nAmsterdam \r\n\r\n\r\nStraatnaam: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\npiet van egmondstraat \r\n\r\n\r\nHuisnummer: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n12d \r\n\r\n\r\nType opdracht: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nFiets reparatie \r\n\r\n\r\nGewenste bekleding: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nPVC / Vinyl \r\n\r\n\r\nAantal treden: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n13 \r\n\r\n\r\nModel fiets: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nfiets met auto (test) \r\n\r\n\r\nProjectbeschrijving: (optioneel) \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia \r\n\r\n\r\nAanhef: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nDhr. \r\n\r\n\r\nAchternaam: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\ntest van test \r\n\r\n\r\nE-mailadres: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\ntest@test.nl <mailto:test@test.nl>  \r\n\r\n\r\nTelefoonnummer: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n0123456789 \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n"
```

and i would like a result like this:

```
{Postcode: "1234aa", Plaats: "Amsterdam", Straatnaam: test van teststraat", Huisnummer: "12d", Type opdracht: "Fiets reparatie", Gewenste bekleding: "PVC", Aantal treden: "13", Model fiets: "fiets met auto (test)",  Projectbeschrijving (optioneel): "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia", Aanhef: "Dhr.", Achternaam: "test van test", E-mailadres: "test@test.nl", Telefoonnummer: "0123456789"}
```

the code that i have at the moment is:

```
let obj = require("./mail.json");

var str = obj.plain;

someText = str
  .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "", "")
  .slice(2)
  .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
  .trim();

console.log(someText);
```

Is this even possible with Nodejs and Expressjs? The keys (eg. Plaats) are always the same, values may change.

I've also managed to remove the line breaks and get a string of all. But after that i'm getting stuck.

I also have the html from the email, would be easier to use the html in the email? Or is this the best way to do it?

Feel free to ask anything or tell a better way if you know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

We start by turning the string into an array using String.split, then we use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to eliminate empty entries.

We then turn the array into a map by using each pair of array entries to as key, value pairs.

```js
const s = "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nPostcode: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n1234aa \r\n\r\n\r\nPlaats: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nAmsterdam \r\n\r\n\r\nStraatnaam: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\npiet van egmondstraat \r\n\r\n\r\nHuisnummer: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n12d \r\n\r\n\r\nType opdracht: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nFiets reparatie \r\n\r\n\r\nGewenste bekleding: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nPVC / Vinyl \r\n\r\n\r\nAantal treden: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n13 \r\n\r\n\r\nModel fiets: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nfiets met auto (test) \r\n\r\n\r\nProjectbeschrijving: (optioneel) \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia \r\n\r\n\r\nAanhef: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nDhr. \r\n\r\n\r\nAchternaam: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\ntest van test \r\n\r\n\r\nE-mailadres: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\ntest@test.nl <mailto:test@test.nl>  \r\n\r\n\r\nTelefoonnummer: \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n0123456789 \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n";

const result = s.split(/[\r\n:]+/).map(x => x.trim()).filter(x => x).reduce((acc, curr, index, arr) => { 
    if (index % 2 === 1) {
        acc[arr[index-1]] = curr; 
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log("Result:", result)
```

Comment: You are the best! Thanks for this!

Comment: I see that there is an extra 'space' after the : in the keys, is it possible to remove these?